# Django File Upload Using a Modelform

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I am currently struggling with uploading files using a Django Modelform.

The form itself looks like this:

```
class AddAzienda(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Azienda
        fields = ('logo', 'nome', 'indirizzo', 'citta', 'provincia', 'cap', 'p_iva', 'rea', 'email', 'top_pdf', 'bottom_pdf', 'is_active')
```

This is the view responsible for the model creation

```
if request.method == "POST":
        form = AddAzienda(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            print("valid")
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            action.send(request.user, verb="ha creato l'azienda", target=instance, ip=get_ip(request))
            messages.success(request, "Azienda <strong>" + instance.nome +  "</strong>  configurata con successo") 
            instance.save()
            return redirect("/aziende/")
    else:
        form = AddAzienda()
    context = {"form":form, "title": "Aggiungi Azienda", "parent":"Amministrazione","page_title": "Aziende configurate", "form_title": "Aggiungi Azienda","pul": "Salva", "link_back":"/aziende/"}
    return render(request, "azienda_add.html", context)
```

The form template contains the correct enctype(according to docs) and the fields seem appropriately named.

This is an example for the logo field:

```
                            <label class="col-lg-2 col-form-label">Logo</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-4">
                                <div class="custom-file">
                                        <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" name="logo" id="id_logo" value="{{azienda.logo.url}}" required>
                                        <label class="custom-file-label" for="id_logo">Seleziona file</label>
                                </div>
```

Can you guys help me?

Thanks

Comment: What is the error that you are getting ?

Comment: i am getting no errors; the form is just not validating(which is weird)

Comment: can you  paste the output of form.errors?

Comment: <ul class="errorlist"><li>provincia<ul class="errorlist"><li>Questo campo è obbligatorio.</li></ul></li></ul>
It appears that I forgot a field... So sorry about that!

Comment: post your complete html form code